# When should Content-Type be application/json

Tags: php, javascript, json

My server is sending data to the client.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($jsondata);
```

What is the benefit of the header?  It encodes the data, but doesn't appear to have any visual effects in the various browsers that I tested it.  I've also seen it break a fileupload plugin (Valum's I think but don't recall).  Lastly, if my server is only returning true/false (or 1/0, or success/null), should I still encode the response?

So, to recap my question, when and why should Content-Type be application/json?

Comment: Also, does it have any effect if part of the downloaded data includes NULL?  In other words, will the client receive that data point as null, or as "null"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: the content-type should be `application/json` whenever you're serving JSON data. It's just a matter of declaring the data properly, like having the right license plates on your car or an ingredients list on a bag of chips.

Whether there is a visual representation of the data in the browser is another issue, that's not the main reason why you serve a content type. (I know of no browser that shows a nice tree view for JSON data. It would be nice though!)

> Lastly, if my server is only returning true/false (or 1/0, or success/null), should I still encode the response?

It depends on what the client expects, but the best policy is usually to be consistent in what you output, i.e. always JSON encode it if your other services use JSON encoding as well.

Comment: Thanks Pekka,  So, if my client script is just if(ajax_response==1) {do_something}, still encode it?

Comment: @user well, if the response will *never* be JSON, but always just 0 or 1, then I guess it's not really necessary. But if your other Ajax sources use JSON, you may want to encode that one as well for consistency sake. It's down to your preference really.

Comment: Thanks Pekka.  I will do as you suggest even though it doesn't appear to bring any benefit, but is just the right thing to do.  My whole purpose of posting this question was to determine whether doing so would prevent null from being displayed as "null"

Comment: @user yeah. One small advantage is arguably that if you output null, it could be a PHP error that gets hidden by error reporting. Whereas a JSON structure that contains null is a clear sign that the service is working, and the response is empty. But it's a question of preference really.

Answer (score 0):

It should force the browser to try to download it as a .json file. Javascript (JQuery for example) will parse it as json rather than text/html.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the header when the data is in-fact JSON. That is to say looks like `{...}` or `[...]` (or, in this instance, it's served using `json_encode`).

Also, it probably doesn't have any effect on a browser because most (without a plugin) render it as straight text, but does make it more concise what the data it returning. Also, libraries like `jQuery` use this header to process the response (if it's not manually supplied in the call).